# How do I use Merchant Ships on Napoleon: Total War?

Tags: napoleon-total-war

I know battle ships can be used for:

- piracy
- troop transport
- fight other ships

The merchant ship however seems ill fitted for all those purposes.
When and how should I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send them to trade posts, which will increase your trade income.

Comment: They can also transport troops